# What limits the performance of Apache configuration with lots of threads?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, apachebench

We were playing around with Apache 2.2 and mod_wsgi configuration on Linux 3.8 to test its behaviour under heavy concurrent traffic. We used ApacheBench (v2.3) to create the traffic from the same machine.

We got the setup working pretty well with 1000 threads (10 processes with 100 threads) but ran into problems when trying to scale up from there. With 10000 threads (10 processes 1000 threads) the server actually got slower and started to perform really badly with the same amount of concurrent requests.

What is the limiting factor for performance with lots of Apache threads? Why is 10000 threads performing worse than 1000 threads? What limits the number of threads anyway? We realize that on usual web services 10000 concurrent connections is not everyday business but we are trying to gain better understanding of web server scalability and different types of web servers.

Here's our mpm worker setup for 1000 threads which worked pretty well.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers           10
    MinSpareThreads      1000
    MaxSpareThreads      1000
    ThreadLimit          1000
    ThreadsPerChild       100
    MaxClients           1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild     0
</IfModule>
```

Mpm worker setup for 10000 threads. This setup was 5x slower.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers           10
    MinSpareThreads     10000
    MaxSpareThreads     10000
    ThreadLimit         10000
    ThreadsPerChild      1000
    MaxClients          10000
    MaxRequestsPerChild     0
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not even sure where to start as to why using that many threads in Apache is a bad idea. I would suggest you as a start go watch my PyCon talks:

- http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/
- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/

The short answer is that if you have a real need to handle large numbers of truly concurrent long running requests on a single server, you probably should not be using Apache. You should be using an event based (async) system for those specific requests that have those non standard requirements. In other words, you don't need to switch your whole application to the async model, instead vertically partition your application and subset out the URLs that have the requirement which is different to the rest of your application. That way you can tailor the hosting to the requirements of each and not force your whole application to run under the constraints imposed by a small part of your application.

Now in reality though, most of the time when people think they need to be able to handle such insane number of concurrent requests on one server, they don't. For requests with a short response time, to handle 10000 requests per second, you do not need 10000 threads. This is because in each 1 second time slot, you can handle more than 1 request.

The one thing that can screw this up though is slow clients and keep alive. This is the killer for Apache. So, go stick nginx in front of it as a proxy and turn off keep alive in Apache, but leave keep alive on in nginx. Using nginx as a proxy will isolate Apache from slow clients and allow it to perform better with less resources. This is because a request is only handed off to Apache when it would generally have all the information in the request so as to allow it to handle the request immediately. Thus is isn't tied up and wasting resources waiting on a slow client.

If you do have that requirement for very long running requests (long polling), for a subset of requests, then have nginx proxy just those URLs to a separate async based server. That way you don't have to deal with the pain of using async systems in the rest of your otherwise normal web application.

This all said, also remember that the web server is not usually going to be your bottleneck. Who cares if the server can handle 10000+ requests per second if your actual web application stack, including database, can only handle 10 requests per second. That is going to be your real problem and if you don't improve your web application performance, tweaking the web server is going to make no difference at all. The only solution would be to horizontally scale and have more than one host and load balance across them.

In order to find the real bottlenecks you are going to need performance monitoring on your real world application, with real traffic from real users. You can see more about performance monitoring in my talks.

Comment: Your answer was very educating, thank you. Hope those PyCon links will be up soon. But. While our overall goal is actually to understand the theory of different web server types (towards which your answer helped alot), with this SO question, we aim to understand the limitations of numbers of threads in a thread based web server. Is it physical memory? Or is it related to context switching overhead perhaps?

Comment: Links should already work. For Python, depends on application as to what limitation is. Can be memory, can be number of concurrent requests, can be GIL mutex contention in threads. Lots of factors can come into play.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton It is the year 2021 and your links are broken. I wish you had put those talks on youtube. Kindly share a new link if you can. Thanks